# AMS Book and custom enumerated lists

Tags: lists, enumerate, amsbook

I use `amsbook` class.

I've added the following to the preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\arabic{enumi}$^\circ$}
```

Now `enumerate` list item numbers look like:

```
(1^$\circ$)
```

Why the parentheses in list item numbers were not removed when I renewed `\theenumi`? How to remove the parentheses?

Answer (score 3):

Almost all roads containing lists lead to `enumitem`. You can use `enumitem` to tweak the list as you want.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\arabic*$^\circ$,ref=\arabic*$^\circ$}
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item one
    \item two \label{item:some}
    \item three
  \end{enumerate}
  \ref{item:some}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you insist on using your method, you have to renew `labelenumi` which is responsible for printing the item numbers.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\arabic{enumi}$^\circ$}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi}   %% this needed
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item one
    \item two \label{item:some}
    \item three
  \end{enumerate}
  \ref{item:some}
\end{document}
```