# How to change colon into dot in description list?

Tags: lists, enumitem, description

I use `amsbook` document class.

In `description` environment there is a colon after every item label.

I want dot instead colon. How?

Note that I already use `\usepackage{enumitem}` as it was suggested in an answer to [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238719/ams-book-and-custom-enumerated-lists).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to redefine `\descriptionlabel`, nothing that `enumitem` is supposed to be able to do. This is the standard definition

```
\newcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{%
  \hspace\labelsep \upshape\bfseries #1:%
}
```

so you want to say

```
\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{%
  \hspace\labelsep \upshape\bfseries #1.%
}
```

in your document preamble.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{%
  \hspace\labelsep \upshape\bfseries #1.%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[Gnu] A big animal
\item[Gnat] A small animal
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Set the way the label is formatted using the `before` key (mentioned in the [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) (p 4)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{description}
  \item[abc] one
  \item[def] two
  \item[ghi] three
\end{description}

\begin{description}[before={\renewcommand\makelabel[1]{\bfseries ##1.}}]
  \item[abc] one
  \item[def] two
  \item[ghi] three
\end{description}

\end{document}
```