# itemize - Customized items

Tags: itemize

In the following MWE I would like to have automatically the labels of items shaped in bold and the colons added instead of being typed.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item[ALG :]
          méthode de type ALG-ébrique

    \item[ARI :]
          méthode de type ARI-thmétique

    \item[GÉO :]
          méthode de type GÉO-métrique
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: To make the font bold: `\begin{itemize}[font=\bfseries]` Alternatively, you might be interested in `description` instead of `itemize`. For a description list with automatically added colons, take a look at this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238763/134144

Comment: I know this environment but it does not align the colons.

Comment: [How to align description item labels on the right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46586/134144) should help solve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could define a new list to do the formatting automatically by changing how `\item` behaves.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\let\olditem\item
\newlist{methods}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[methods]{%
    align=right,
    before=\changeitem,
    font=\bfseries,
    after=\let\item\olditem
}
\newcommand*{\changeitem}{%
    \renewcommand*{\item}[1][]{%
        \olditem[##1 :]
    }%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{methods}
    \item[ALG]
          méthode de type ALG-ébrique
    \item[ARI]
          méthode de type ARI-thmétique
    \item[GÉO]
          méthode de type GÉO-métrique
\end{methods}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Useful and versatile solution. I like that !

Answer (score 3):

Here is a completely different approach using a `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\bfseries}r<{ :}@{~}l}
    ALG & méthode de type ALG-ébrique \\
    ARI & méthode de type ARI-thmétique\\
    GÉO & méthode de type GÉO-métrique\\
\end{tabular}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\bfseries}r<{ :}@{~}l}
    ALG & méthode de type ALG-ébrique \\
    ARI & méthode de type ARI-thmétique\\
    GÉO & méthode de type GÉO-métrique\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Easy to use and to transform to an environment.